# RecyclerView no se actualiza cuando abro la aplicación

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, recyclerview

estoy haciendo una red social en kotlin + Firebase, y actualmente tengo una especie de problema de que no logro terminar de solucionar, al iniciar la aplicación aparece inicialmente en el fragmento dashboard donde se ven los post tuyos y de tus amigos, además de agregar alguno nuevo, el problema es que al iniciar la aplicación no entiendo porque no se actualiza automáticamente el Recyclerview al descargar los post de Firestore, tengo que manualmente moverme de fragmento y volver al dashboard para que aparezcan.

Entiendo que cuando se pinta la app todavía no aparecen los datos porque tiene que descargarlos, pero con este código deberían pintarse también una vez descargados, cual podría ser el problema?

**Asi se ve al Iniciar la app:**

[image: Asi se ve al iniciar la app:]

**Asi se ve luego de moverme a cualquier otro fragmento y regresar al dashboard:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**DashboardFragment:**

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_dashboard) {
private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
private var dbposts= mutableListOf<Post>()

private var recycler: RecyclerView?=null
private var itemadapter: PostAdapter?=null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

    root!!.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.addpostbtn).setOnClickListener{
        goto(context as AppCompatActivity, AddPost::class.java.newInstance())
    }

    db.collection("post").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener { res, err ->
        val posts = res!!.toObjects(Post::class.java)
        val fpost = posts.filter {isFriend(it!!.id)}
        dbposts.clear()
        if(dbposts.addAll(fpost)) {
            pintarRes(root)
        }
    }

    return root
}

private fun isFriend(id:String):Boolean{
    var isFriend = false
    for(it in DataHolder.friends){
        if(it.id == id || DataHolder.profileUser.id == id){
            isFriend = true
        }
    }
    return isFriend
}

@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
private fun pintarRes(root:View){
    recycler = root.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.posts)
    itemadapter = context?.let { PostAdapter(it,dbposts) }
    recycler?.adapter = itemadapter
    itemadapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

**PostAdapter:**

```
class PostAdapter(var context: Context, var listItems: List<Post>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    var alias = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.postalias)
    var textpost = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.posttext)
    var likeBtn = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.postlikebtn)
    var shareBtn = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.postsharebtn)
    var pfp = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.postpfp)
    var date = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.postdate)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_post, parent, false)
    return PostAdapter.ViewHolder(view)
}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = listItems[position]
    holder.alias.text = item.alias
    holder.textpost.text = item.text

    val dt = SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm a")
    holder.date.text = dt.format(item.date)

    if (item.avatarURL != "") {
        Glide.with(holder.view).load(item.avatarURL.toUri()).into(holder.pfp)
    } else {
        holder.pfp.setImageDrawable(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_portrait))
    }

    holder.shareBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val sendIntent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, item.text)
            type = "text/plain"
        }
        val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
        context.startActivity(shareIntent)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return listItems.size
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/postrootlayout"
tools:context=".DashboardFragment">

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addpostbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/posts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/view_post" /> </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Qué es `DataHolder`? Puede haber un error ahí.

Comment: Dataholder es un companion object donde guardo los datos del usuario logeado y Profile es un data class de Strings: 
class DataHolder {
    companion object{
        var profileUser: Profile = Profile()
        var friends = mutableListOf<Usuario>()
    }
}

Comment: Agregalo en la pregunta y muestra también en que momento cargas datos en la lista `friends`

Comment: vale, ya lo arregle gracias a tu comentario, el problema era que esta moviéndome al dashboard antes de tener la lista de amigos completamente descargada, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema era que en el loginActivity (cuando se autentica al usuario) no estaba esperando a que se terminara de descargar la lista de amigos de la bbdd antes de moverse a la activity donde esta el dashboardFragment, lo arregle gracias al comentario de [Sinner of the System](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/198326/sinner-of-the-system)

No me había dado cuanta ya que el acceso a la bbdd para descargar los Friends, lo tenia como una función aparte, por lo que no había puesto el addOnSuccessListener antes de moverme de actividad

**Antes:**

```
private fun getUserProfile(id:String){
    db.collection("user").document(id).collection("Data").document("Profile").get().addOnSuccessListener { res ->
        try {
            DataHolder.profileUser = res.toObject(Profile::class.java)!!
        }catch (e: NullPointerException){
            val pref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.prefs_file), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            pref.clear()
            pref.apply()
        }
    }.addOnSuccessListener {
        db.collection("user").document(id).collection("Friends").get().addOnSuccessListener { res ->
            for(doc in res) {
                val friend = doc.toObject(Usuario::class.java)
                val id2 = friend.id
                db.collection("user").document(id2).collection("Data").document("Profile").get().addOnSuccessListener {
                    val user = it.toObject(Usuario::class.java)
                    if (user != null) {
                        DataHolder.friends.add(user)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        goto(this, MainScreen::class.java.newInstance())
        finish()
    }
}
```

**Despues:**

```
private fun getUserProfile(id:String){
    db.collection("user").document(id).collection("Data").document("Profile").get().addOnSuccessListener { res ->
        try {
            DataHolder.profileUser = res.toObject(Profile::class.java)!!
        }catch (e: NullPointerException){
            val pref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.prefs_file), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            pref.clear()
            pref.apply()
        }
    }.addOnSuccessListener {
        db.collection("user").document(id).collection("Friends").get().addOnSuccessListener { res ->
            for(doc in res) {
                val friend = doc.toObject(Usuario::class.java)
                val id2 = friend.id
                db.collection("user").document(id2).collection("Data").document("Profile").get().addOnSuccessListener {
                    val user = it.toObject(Usuario::class.java)
                    if (user != null) {
                        DataHolder.friends.add(user)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.addOnSuccessListener {
            goto(this, MainScreen::class.java.newInstance())
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega más detalles para ampliar tu respuesta, como código que funcione o citas de documentación.

Comment: Me alegra que lo hayas solucionado pero procura que tus preguntas y respuestas sean de ayuda para toda la comunidad, no sólo para ti. Como está ahora dudo que pueda ser útil para alguién. Deberías mostrar dónde estaba el problema y qué cambio hiciste para resolverlo.

Comment: si, tienes razón, ya arregle la respuesta